# How do I get a list of month names from two date columns?

Tags: mysql

Example of a table:

| ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-05-01 |

How do I get the list of months name between two date columns as the range?
Something like:

```
|ID| Months |
|--|--------|
|1 | January|
|1 | Febuary|
|1 | March  |
|1 | April  |
|2 | March  |
|2 | April  |
|2 | May    |
```

Most of the examples I have found all manually input the date from one column. I tried monthname(), datediff() but the diff only calculates the difference and not list them

Comment: Why would you want mysql to handle that kind of process?

Comment: Because I would like to use the months name to filter some data in my php

Comment: Why not let php handle that?

Comment: How about building a reference table like this:
January21: 2021-01-01, 2021-01-31
This way you can easily compare ranges

Comment: @lvil that would be ugly. I suggest just let php handle that kind of data manipulation.

Comment: @Techuila right, very ugly

Comment: If I were to let php handle it, how do I go bout with that? I wasnt sure what to look up to help with the data

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL8.0 you can do this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    MONTH(StartDate) as M,
    MONTHNAME(StartDate) as MonthName,
    1 as X
  FROM fromto
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cte.ID,
    MONTH(DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL X MONTH)),
    MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL X MONTH)),
    X+1
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN fromto on fromto.ID=cte.ID
  WHERE DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL X MONTH)<=EndDate
)
SELECT ID,M,MonthName FROM cte order by ID,M;
```

output:

```
+------+------+-----------+
| ID   | M    | MonthName |
+------+------+-----------+
|    1 |    1 | January   |
|    1 |    2 | February  |
|    1 |    3 | March     |
|    1 |    4 | April     |
|    2 |    3 | March     |
|    2 |    4 | April     |
|    2 |    5 | May       |
+------+------+-----------+
```

The table `fromto` in above example is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `fromto` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` date DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `fromto` VALUES (1,'2021-01-01','2021-04-01'),(2,'2021-03-01','2021-05-01');
```

Without `WITH` (prior to MySQL 8.0), one could do:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS counter;
CREATE TABLE counter(i int primary key);
INSERT INTO counter VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);

SELECT
   id,
   MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL i MONTH))
FROM 
   fromto
CROSS JOIN  counter
WHERE DATE_ADD(StartDate,INTERVAL i MONTH)<=EndDate
ORDER BY id,2;
```

As much values as needed should be added to this `counter` table.

Comment: I know the With statement won't work with myphpadmin. Is there a way I can use somewhat of a different query to achieve the same result?

Comment: The With statement has nothing to do with myphpadmin. It only has to do with the version of MySQL.  You need, at least, 8.0 to make it work.

Comment: Yeah I did some research about it, seems like my myphpadmin uses mariadb, i tried changing it to mysql 8.0 but errors keep on happening when I try to start the mysql on xampp. I tried to change the ports and all still no luck. Is there a tutorial somewhere to change the server on xampp? because the error that keeps showing up is "MYSQL shutdown unexpectedly"

Comment: You should really leave myphpadmin out of this discussion. That is a tool to connect to a database. That database can me MySQL or MariaDB. If you have MySQL  it should be 8.0+ to use `WITH`. Or mariadb, where `WITH` seems to be supported from version [10.2.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/)

Comment: A website that compares MySQL vs MariaDB (sep2020) can be found [here](https://www.xplenty.com/blog/mariadb-vs-mysql-everything-you-need-to-know/)